# Weblogic SingletonService having infinite loop not working for multiple SingletonService

Tags: loops, weblogic, infinite

I have to deploy multiple weblogic singleton service; where each of the singletonservice contains an infinite loop within the activate method. There is no thread sleep in the infinite loop. If I deploy a 2 instances (2 Singletonservice application containing infinite loop) then it is working fine. But once I deploy 3rd one, then any 2 of them is running. To debug the issue, I found, if I remove the infinite loop then all 3 of them are running. Any idea why it is having the problem with infinite loop. I am using Weblogic 12c with JDK7 & having 2 managedsevers in the cluster. I am deploying the SingletonService applications as EAR component & each of them is deployed as different EAR app.

Thanks
Sourav

Comment: Are all 3 ear files in the active state when you have the problem? Are they all named differently? Are you running as a cluster? I doubt the actual problem has anything to do with your app containing a loop

Comment: Yes. All three are in Active State & also all of them had different names for EAR as well as for SingletonService class name also. I am also deploying them in cluster. Any suggestion?

Comment: Resolved the issue by putting the infinite loop within thread. With this all Singletonservices work perfectly.